# How to copy values to 6 columns before the selected cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is simple, but this is my first code in google apps script.

```
function copy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var row = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A97:H99').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

How do I copy the values from the selected / active cell to 6 columns before it? would be something similar to: Copy to active cell - 6.

I made this code, which already copies what I need, however it is pasting inside the selected cell itself. I need -6 columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copy1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('A1:H3').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange().offset(0,-6), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```